# python: Convert excel to csv

Tags: python-3.x, csv, spreadsheet

I have some lines of code which was supposed to convert plethora of excel spreadsheet in my current working directory to `csv` files.

Unfortunately after running this code I got an error in line 21.
What could have lead to this error?
Thanks in advance.

```
python
import os
import csv
import openpyxl

for spreadsheet in os.listdir('.'):
    if spreadsheet.endswith('.xlsx'):
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(spreadsheet)
        for sheet_name in wb.get_sheet_names():
            sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
            csv_file = open(sheet_name + '.csv', 'w', newline='')
            csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            for row_num in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
                row_data = []
                for col_num in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
                    row_data.append(sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col_num).value)
                for row in row_data:
                    csv_writer.writerow(row)
            csv_file.close()
```

I expected to have converted `csv` files. Below is what I got.

> C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:10: 
>   DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_names (Use 
>   wb.sheetnames).

Remove the `CWD` from `sys.path` while we load stuff.

> C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:11: 
>   DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_by_name (Use 
>   wb[sheetname]).

This is added back by `InteractiveShellApp.init_path()`

```py
Error  Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-29-1b50f926f2e2> in <module>() 
     19 
     20                 for row in row_data:
---> 21                     csv_writer.writerow(row)
     22             csv_file.close()
Error: iterable expected, not int
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing your last lines by that:

```
for row_num in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
    row_data = []
    for col_num in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
        row_data.append(sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col_num).value)
    csv_writer.writerow(row_data)
csv_file.close()
```

When you do `for row in row_data:`, you are in reality iterating over single values (which are integers)

Comment: @ olinox14,when I replaced the code,I got this error:  ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: Check the indentation of your `csv_file.close()` line, it must be executed **after** the `for row_num` loop. Or even better: use the [with](https://pythontips.com/2014/01/15/the-open-function-explained/) keyword to open your file